Batch export rasters using Google Earth Engine
I’ve recently created some code to create monthly mean images of Land Surface Temperature for my field site. Link to the code is here
I’m trying to batch export the image collection (monthlycelsius) as individual rasters and I stumbled upon your code here.
I tried it and I can’t seem to get it working. I get a weird comment on my console when I run it.
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch')

batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(monthlycelsius, 'Abberton_Rasters',
                {scale: 30,
                 region: ROI.getInfo()["coordinates"],
                 maxPixels:1e13,
                 type: 'float'})

Image.date: Image '0' has a 'system:time_start' property which is not a number: 2023-01-01T00:00:00

Is what is causing this simply the format of my image date?

I haven't used the module you've linked here, but I think the following essentially does what you want:
// make ImageCollection into a List for easy iteration
var monthlycelsius_ls = monthlycelsius.toList(monthlycelsius.size())
// get number of images in the collection
var num_imgs = monthlycelsius.size().getInfo()

// loop through the image collection and export each image as it comes
for (var i=0; i < num_imgs; i++) {
  var img_to_export = ee.Image(monthlycelsius_ls.get(i));
  
  Export.image.toDrive(img_to_export)
}

You'll just need to change the exact parameters you want in the Export.image.toDrive() function, but otherwise it works for me.
You will have to click "Run" for each image, but from looking at the module you linked, I think you would've had to do that anyway.

Is there anyway of labelling each image with the date extracted from each image, using the fileNamePrefix: argument in export.image.toDrive? At the moment I've used fileNamePrefix: 'LST_' + i, to differentiate them, by image number. However, by date would be easier, but can't quite figure out how to do that.

using img_to_export.get("date") will get you the date object for the image. From there, you can format it however you want using the .format() method of ee.Date. You'll also have to do a .getInfo() before using it in the fileNamePrefix or else you'll be stuck with a gross looking JSON formatted object!
e.g. var date_formatted = ee.Date(img_to_export.get("date")).format("<enter_date_format_here>").getInfo()
